# How to extract value from json array with QJsonDocument format

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm getting a json format like this and I want to get the value of *"Duration", "Id", "LoadCumulLimit" and "Notes"*.

`QJsonDocument({"d":{"results":[{"Duration":"420.000","Id":"123456789XYZ","LoadCumulLimit":"15.000","NavWpNioshToOpNoish":{"__deferred":{"uri":"http://xxx/WorkplaceNOISHDataSet('123456789XYZ')/NavWpNioshToOpNoish"}},"Notes":"123456789XYZ","__metadata":{"id":"xxx/WorkplaceNOISHDataSet('123456789XYZ')","type":"xxx.WorkplaceNOISHData","uri":"xxx/WorkplaceNOISHDataSet('123456789XYZ')"}}]}})`

I tried to do this but it doesn't work and it return empty with array
`

```
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(content.toUtf8());
QJsonArray documentArray = document.array();

QStringList wordList;

for (const QJsonValue &i : documentArray)
{
    //qInfo() << i.toString() << endl;
    wordList << i.toString();
}
```

Could you guys give me a help or any suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the `QJsonDocument` to a `QVariant`. Then you can use `QVariantMap` or `QVariantList` to walk the document and use the appropriate `toString()` or `toDouble()` to retrieve the values.

The following is hard-coded to your JSON there are only minimal validation checks included. (i.e. it is a disclaimer that the code is presented for educational purposes only and made not be production ready).

```cpp
bool parse()
{
    QString json = "{\"d\":{\"results\":[{\"Duration\":\"420.000\",\"Id\":\"123456789XYZ\",\"LoadCumulLimit\":\"15.000\",\"NavWpNioshToOpNoish\":{\"__deferred\":{\"uri\":\"http://xxx/WorkplaceNOISHDataSet('123456789XYZ')/NavWpNioshToOpNoish\"}},\"Notes\":\"123456789XYZ\",\"__metadata\":{\"id\":\"xxx/WorkplaceNOISHDataSet('123456789XYZ')\",\"type\":\"xxx.WorkplaceNOISHData\",\"uri\":\"xxx/WorkplaceNOISHDataSet('123456789XYZ')\"}}]}}";
    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json.toUtf8());
    if (document.isEmpty() || document.isNull()) return false;
    QVariantMap root = document.toVariant().toMap();
    if (root.isEmpty()) return false;
    QVariantMap d = root["d"].toMap();
    if (d.isEmpty()) return false;
    QVariantList results = d["results"].toList();
    if (results.isEmpty()) return false;
    foreach (QVariant varResult, results)
    {
        QVariantMap result = varResult.toMap();
        if (result.isEmpty()) return false;
        bool ok = true;
        double duration = result["Duration"].toDouble(&ok);
        if (!ok) return false;
        QString id = result["Id"].toString();
        if (id.isEmpty() || id.isNull()) return false;
        double loadCumulLimit = result["LoadCumulLimit"].toDouble(&ok);
        if (!ok) return false;
        QString notes = result["Notes"].toString();
        if (!notes.isEmpty() || notes.isNull()) return false;
        qDebug() << id << duration << loadCumulLimit << notes; // "123456789XYZ" 420 15 "123456789XYZ"
    }
    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use `QJsonDocument`, `QJsonValue` and `QJsonArray` to walk the document and use the corresponding `toString()` and `toDouble()` to retrieve the values. Again, there are minimal validation checks included:

```cpp
bool parse2()
{
    QString json = "{\"d\":{\"results\":[{\"Duration\":\"420.000\",\"Id\":\"123456789XYZ\",\"LoadCumulLimit\":\"15.000\",\"NavWpNioshToOpNoish\":{\"__deferred\":{\"uri\":\"http://xxx/WorkplaceNOISHDataSet('123456789XYZ')/NavWpNioshToOpNoish\"}},\"Notes\":\"123456789XYZ\",\"__metadata\":{\"id\":\"xxx/WorkplaceNOISHDataSet('123456789XYZ')\",\"type\":\"xxx.WorkplaceNOISHData\",\"uri\":\"xxx/WorkplaceNOISHDataSet('123456789XYZ')\"}}]}}";
    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json.toUtf8());
    if (document.isEmpty() || document.isNull()) return false;
    QJsonValue d = document["d"];
    if (d.isNull() || d.isUndefined()) return false;
    QJsonArray results = d["results"].toArray();
    if (results.isEmpty()) return false;
    foreach (QJsonValue result, results)
    {
        double duration = result["Duration"].toDouble();
        QString id = result["Id"].toString();
        if (id.isEmpty() || id.isNull()) return false;
        double loadCumulLimit = result["LoadCumulLimit"].toDouble();
        QString notes = result["Notes"].toString();
        if (!notes.isEmpty() || notes.isNull()) return false;
        qDebug() << id << duration << loadCumulLimit << notes; // "123456789XYZ" 420 15 "123456789XYZ"
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have followed with your option 2 but I got the error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'QJsonDocument' and 'const char [2]')
 QJsonValue d = document["d"];

Do you have any suggestions for me?
Anyway, your first option is correct and I get the things I want but could you please help me to explain the error above? I want to gain more knowledge

Comment: That's odd. The syntax worked for me, but I am using Qt6. The `operator[]` does take a `QString`. It could be that your compiler isn't mapping "d" to a QString? I am not sure why though. I suppose you could try `QJsonValue d = document[QString("d")];` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
    object d {
        object results {
            [ { several objects to be extracted} ]
        }
    }
```

To extract a value of an object by given a key, call `operator[](key)` on `QJsonValue`.
When you have an array, to extract its first item call `operator[](0)` on this array. When you have found an object at desired key, you can convert its value to the value of specified type by `toString/toInt/toDouble` etc. methods of `QJsonValue`.

Short version:

```
    QJsonValue item0 = document["d"]["results"].toArray()[0];
    QStringList wordList;
    wordList << item0["Duration"].toString() << item0["Id"].toString() << item0["LoadCumulLimit"].toString() << item0["Notes"].toString();
```

the longer version:

```
    QJsonValue dObj = document["d"];
    QJsonValue resultsObj = dObj["results"];
    QJsonArray resultsArray = resultsObj.toArray();
    QJsonValue item0 = resultsArray[0];
    QStringList wordList;
    wordList << item0["Duration"].toString() << item0["Id"].toString() << item0["LoadCumulLimit"].toString() << item0["Notes"].toString();
```

Comment: Hi, I have followed your suggestion but I have an error like this "error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'QJsonDocument' and 'const char [2]')
             QJsonValue dObj = nioshWPData["d"];".
Do you have any suggestions for me

Comment: What QT version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using QT5 and compiler is "i686-4.9.2-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-rev1"

Comment: What is the minor QT version ? `operator[]` overloads are supported since QT 5.10 version. If you have earlier verion, try to use `niosWPData.object()["d"]`.